# How are `glTexEnv`, `glColor4x` and `glBlendFunc` related in OpenGL ES 1.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, alphablending

I'm looking at SurfaceFlinger, i.e. the the code that is doing the composition in Android, and I have trouble understanding some of the OpenGL ES 1.0 calls as I've only programmed ES 2.0 code.

Here goes the piece of code that interests me:

```
glTexEnvx(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

What it is supposed to be doing is blending a texture into the buffer.

Why does one need the `glTextEnvx` and `glColor4x` calls? Isn't `glBlendFunc` enough for achieving blending?

I *know* my question is naive, but I still don't understand what is `glTexEnvx` for even after reading the [docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glTexEnv.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glTexEnv()` sets the texture environment mode. `GL_REPLACE` tells the renderer to skip the current color (for example, from `glColor4()`) and instead tells the renderer to use your texture's colors for every corresponding pixel. If you, instead of `GL_REPLACE`, use `GL_MODULATE`, then your `glColor4()` call will be included together with the texture's colors when the renderer sets a pixel's color.

Your `glColor4()` call shouldn't be doing anything (when using `GL_REPLACE`) that can be seen on your object.

About your `glBlendFunc()` arguments:

`GL_ONE` is using the current color that comes from your incoming primitive, which we call *source*. `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` is multiplying the *destination* (which is the currently stored pixel in the frame buffer) by (1 - source alpha value).

Normally, when you're not using textures, you achieve a transparent effect from *color* primitives when the `glColor4()` contains an alpha value where 1 equals fully opaque and 0 fully transparent.

Comment: After you had explained it all I read the doc again and it made sense now. However, I think you're wrong that `GL_MODULATE` uses the color set by `glColor`. According to the doc `GL_MODULATE` uses only the fragment and texture colors, whereas `GL_BLEND` uses the env color.

Comment: @Albus: `GL_MODULATE` means that it will take the texture color and multiply it by the incoming color. Try to Google: *what does `GL_MODULATE`?* and you'll see other posts stating the same fact.

Comment: Well, dunno. According to the [doc](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glTexEnv.html), the color output for `GL_MODULATE` would be: `color_of_the_texture * color_of_the_fragment`, whereas for `GL_BLEND`: `(1 - color_of_the texture) * color_of_the_fragment + color_of_the_texture * env_color`. That is, the env color comes in only for `GL_BLEND`. Not trying to be obstinate, sry. Your answer did help me a lot, but according to the doc you seem to be wrong or I am misreading it somehow.

Comment: @Albus: The fragment, in this context, is actually the pixel color which already is in the frame buffer.

Comment: @Albus: Oh, no problems. It is always good to understand the whole concept then just *suspecting* to know. :)

Comment: Thanks, mate! So, `GL_MODULATE` would use the pixel color from the fb, not the color set by `glColor4x`, whereas `GL_BLEND` would *also* use the *environment color*, which actually is the color set by `glColor4x`. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @Pompedevelo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1869/discussion-between-albus-dumbledore-and-pompe-de-velo)

Comment: Well, when you are calling `glColor4()`, you are setting a new pixel color for your primitive and that will be the *fragment* color (or whatever everyone says :)). `GL_BLEND` will take both texture's colors and a pixel's color when calculating the blending when we use `GL_MODULATE`. However, when we use `GL_REPLACE` it is essentially saying to remove the fragment color when blending (and, for example, only use a texture´s alpha layer to determine transparent parts), in this context.